# как сделать чтобы программа отделяла вводимые цифры от слов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать чтобы программа отделяла вводимые цифры от слов. Сейчас она определяет только цифры.  И в зависимости от ввода слова или цифр делала то или иное действие. Вот часть кода:

```
def output(event):  # Обработка вводимого текста и неправильного ввода
    txt = entry1.get()
    try:
        if int(txt) > 0:
            chem_element(int(txt))
        else:
            window_open("Введите положительный номер элемента")
    except ValueError:
        window_open("Введите корректный номер элемента")
```

Тут полный код - https://github.com/maxim58r/Chemistry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt = entry1.get()
if txt.isnumeric():
    n = int(txt)
    if n > 0:
        chem_element(n)
    else:
        window_open("Введите положительный номер элемента")
else:
    # В переменной txt текст
    ...
```